# nested dictionary with values sometimes dictionary lists, sometimes a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

I would like to extract the keys and value into a nested dictionary with list comprehension,
one of the dictionary keys sometimes has the value a dictionary and sometimes a list of dictionaries

```
Data={"main": {"sub_main": [   
    
    {"id": "995", "item": "850", "price": {"ref": "razorback", "value": "250"}},
    
    {"id": "953", "item": "763", "price": [{"ref": "razorback", "value": "250"},{"ref": "sumatra", "value": "170"},{"ref": "ligea", "value": "320"} ]}, 
    
    ]}}
```

I tried with this list comprehension:

```
result = [item["price"] for item in Data["main"]["sub_main"]]
```

how to output only certain values from the "price" key according to a filter on the "id" key , for example, output only the values of the "price" key for the "id" key which has the value "953"

thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'if' statement in your list comprehension to extract data specific to an id.

`result = [item["price"] for item in Data["main"]["sub_main"] if item["id"]=="953"]`

Output

`[[{'ref': 'razorback', 'value': '250'}, {'ref': 'sumatra', 'value': '170'}, {'ref': 'ligea', 'value': '320'}]]`

result variable will only inlcude the filtered data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).